# How to remove spacing between links with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to recreate 4 'buttons' for a web view of an app that are static and in a fixed position on mobile view only. The idea is they take up 100% of the width of the screen to make it seem like a native app.

However, there looks to be spacing between each element and I don't know how to get rid of it. If I set the width of the boxes to 24% they'll fit on one line but with spacing. If it's at 25% then I get 3 on one line and the 4th on a separate line underneath.[image]

CSS:

```
.mobileShow {
  display: none;
}



/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .mobileShow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px;
  }
}

#mobileButton {
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 10px 0 !important; 
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

The code is RoR, but essentially it's spitting out normal links.
Code:

```
  <div class="mobileShow">
      <%= link_to "Box 1", "#", class: "btn btn-default", id: "mobileButton"%>
      <%= link_to "Box 2", "#", class: "btn btn-default", id: "mobileButton" %>
      <%= link_to "Box 3", "#", class: "btn btn-default", id: "mobileButton" %>
      <%= link_to "Box 4", "#", class: "btn btn-default", id: "mobileButton" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why you don't use the col-md-* and col-xs-* classes of bootstrap3? (* is a number from 1 to 12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `box-sizing` property in your CSS.
Since you use `padding: 10px;` property, it gives additional element that force other object to adjust automatically. using `box-sizing: border-box;` will help you fix it.

```
#mobileButton {
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 10px 0 !important; 
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*here*/
}
```

You can also read it here :
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Thanks - I wanted to understand why it wasn't working and your explanation helped.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making a button group rather than trying to treat them all individually? Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <%= link_to "Box 1", "#", class: "btn btn-default", id: "mobileButton"%>
  <%= link_to "Box 2", "#", class: "btn btn-default", id: "mobileButton" %>
  <%= link_to "Box 3", "#", class: "btn btn-default", id: "mobileButton" %>
  <%= link_to "Box 4", "#", class: "btn btn-default", id: "mobileButton" %>
</div>
```

I will say, the buttons themselves are not the way I would usually make them, and they also have the same ID which isn't good. I would instead suggest doing something such as:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="mobileButton1">Box 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="mobileButton2">Box 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="mobileButton3">Box 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="mobileButton4">Box 4</a>
</div>
```